# Save gmap plot not including google tiles (the map)

Tags: google-maps, bokeh

Exporting a gmap plot to png (from the Bokeh SaveTool) does not include the map tiles. Just a grey background with lat and long axes and the plot title.
The bokeh tools are also missing.

Have tried on Brave, Chrome and Safari also tried adding a server side save using export_png which works albeit with a strange height and width (even when they are passed). The server side solution is not great as it does not reflect any client side zooms or pans, just the original plot.

I have simplified the plot to just a map with no overlays, still no joy.

```py
from bokeh.models import (GMapPlot, GMapOptions, BoxSelectTool, SaveTool, Plot)
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure, gmap

output_notebook()

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=-33.79822854506091, lng=151.2562823223427, map_type="roadmap", zoom=13)


plot = gmap("myGoogleKey", map_options, height_policy="max", width_policy="max")
plot.title.text = "Sample Plot"
plot.add_tools(BoxSelectTool(), SaveTool())
show(plot)
```

The expected output is what is shown on the screen, the actual output (to file) shows the lat/lng axes and tickers but the entire map area is grey.

This is after allowing plenty of time for the screen load (the screen is loaded)

There are no JavaScript errors in the browser console.

If I zoom (client side) the grid shown on the output png file reflects my location and zoom level - i.e. it knows what i have done but still no map tiles.

Comment: Looks like a bug... BTW: saving as HTML works (using valid API-key).

Comment: A known limitation, not a bug. The save tool can only save the HTML canvas, and a Google map is not pat of that.

Answer (score 0):

The save tool only saves the HTML canvas object. Neither the toolbar, which is a separate DOM object off the canvas, or the Google Map itself, which is a separate DOM object underneath the (transparent) canvas, are included in that. This is simply an intrinsic limitation of the `SaveTool`. It will not be able to save Google Map tiles.

You might try the other non-Google tile renderer options in Bokeh. Those render raster tiles directly on to the HTML canvas. Otherwise, the only options is the `export_png` function.

Comment: It appears I am going backwards. Using CARDOPOSITRON (openstreeetmap) the save button does not work at all. This is a known bug and looks to have been fixed in the dev pipeline. With apologies for the newbie question - how can I install/run/use a dev build of the server so I can export the map?

Comment: You can look at the old docs we used to publish for installing dev builds: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.2.0/docs/installation.html#developer-builds However be aware the reason these docs were removed because we were getting static over the fact that BokehJS resources for dev builds are not guaranteed to be available forever --- despite having been very loud, and 100% clear about this fact, consistently. Dev builds are in ***NO WAY*** suitable for anything "production" or "permanent". Dev builds are suitable for local, temporary testing, and ***NOTHING ELSE***.

Comment: Appreciate that but given there appears to be no way to print a map that has been panned/zoomed using any tile source.... strikes me as a bit of a limitation. I would way rather stick to the production base if there is another way. Absent a solution I might as well stick with gmap and tell the users to do screenshots - tacky imho.

Comment: If you know a way to make it work your contribution would certainly be welcome.

Comment: Well there is a fix on the dev stream so I was hoping that might get deployed sometime. (The fix is for the non Google tile providers)

Comment: Bokeh 1.4 was released today.